# Equivalent convergent conditions in $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

I am doing problems in my instructor's notes. I am stuck at the following problem.

"Let $f_n\in C([0,1])$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$. Show that the
  following two statements are equivalent:

1) For every $\lambda\in C([0,1])^*$ we have $\lambda(f_n)\to
      0$ as $n\to\infty$,

2) $f_n(x)\to 0$ for every $x\in [0,1]$ and $\sup
        ||f_n||_\infty<\infty$."

$(1) \implies (2):$ It turns out I did this part wrong. I used Uniform Boundedness Principle for $f_n$, which is not linear.

$(2) \implies (1):$ I am stuck at this one. I want to prove that $f_n\to 0$ and the rest would be easy. we have

$$
lim_{n\to \infty} ||f_n|| = lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \{|f_n(x)| \}
$$

here I wish I can interchange lim and sup and we are done. Is this approach true and how do we do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I want to prove that $f_n→0$" you won't be able to prove that because it's not true in general. Statement 1) is known as weak convergence and the reason it's "weak" is that it is weaker than regular convergence. I.e. there are functions that converge weakly but do not converge in norm. Weak convergence is also called "convergence in distribution" in the context of probability theory.

Comment: right, so my approaches are all wrong, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's been a while. I know you can prove part of 1 => 2 by looking at the functionals "evaluate at x." Beyond that I would need to think some more. I'm not sure if you need to know exactly what the elements of $C([0,1])^*$ are but maybe it would help.

Comment: yep, the first part of 1=>2 uses exactly evaluations. I attempted the second part with Uniform Boundedness Principle, but I overlooked the conditions so I was wrong

Comment: Look at the second corollary [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Corollaries): "Any weakly bounded subset S in a normed space Y is bounded."

Comment: wow, I thought the principle cannot be used since f_n are not linear. But great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1) \implies (2):$ Take $x \in [0,1]$. Consider the operator $\delta_x$ which maps each $f \in C([0,1])$ to its value $f(x)$, i.e. $\delta_x(f) = f(x).$ Now this operator is centainly linear. It is also bounded as

$$|\delta_x (f)| = |f(x)| \leq ||f||_\infty.$$

Hence $\delta_x \in C([0,1])^*$. From $(1)$ we get

$$f_n(x) = \delta_x (f_n) \rightarrow 0.$$

$f_n$ are unifromly bounded by the uniform boundedness principle as for each $\lambda \in C([0,1])^*$ the sequence of scalars $(\lambda(f_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded (convergent sequences of scalars are always bounded), and hence $(f_n)_n$ is weakly bounded.

$(2) \implies (1):$ Take $\lambda \in C([0,1])^*$. Then $\lambda$ is a complex (or signed) Radon measure by the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem). By $(2)$ we have that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ a.e. and that $\sup_n ||f_n|| := S < \infty$. But then we can use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem with a constant funcion equal to $S$ as a majorant.

$$\lambda(f_n) = \int_0^1 f_n(x) d \lambda(x) \rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: Assume 1). For any $f \in C[0,1]$ let $f^{**}\in C[0,1]^{**},$ where $f^{**}(\lambda)=\lambda (f)$ for $\lambda \in C[0,1]^*.$ Then $|f^{**}(\lambda)|\le \|\lambda\|\cdot \|f\|,$ so $\|f^{**}\|\le \|f\|.$ By Hahn-Banach Theorem there exists $\lambda \in C[0,1]^*$ with $\|\lambda\|\ne 0$ and $|\lambda(f)|=\|f\|\cdot \|\lambda\|,$ so $\|f^{**}\|\ge\|f\|.$ Therefore $\|f^{**}\|=\|f\| $... Now $\{f_n^{**}:n\in \Bbb N\}$ is point-wise bounded so $\infty >\sup_n\|f^{**}\|=\sup_n\|f_n\|$ by Uniform Bounded Principle.